# How to make synchronization between processes using signals?

Tags: c, unix, process, signals, fork

The objective is the parent process should make a child one, the parent prints the even numbers between 1 to 100, the child prints the odd ones. This mechanism should be made using signals (the numbers should be in order obviously e.g. parent:0, child:1, parent:2...) I made the following code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1){
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (pid == 0){
            
        for(int i=0; i<=100; i++){
            if (i % 2 != 0){
                printf("I am the child: %d\n", i);
            }
        }

    } else {
        kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
        for(int i=0; i<=100; i++){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                printf("I am the parent: %d\n", i);
                kill(pid, SIGCONT);
            }
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But the output isn't in the order it should be, the parent prints all of his numbers first, the child follows him. I was wondering if the SIGSTOP and SIGCONT aren't the suitable signals to be used, but there's no other logical solution.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: There is no code in the parent to wait for the child to do its print. Suggest using `sigwait` with `SUGUSR` signals. See the above duplicate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block on a signal and resume only when that signal is received. Regarding which signal to use, you could use any that can be blocked (any signal excluding `SIGKILL`, `SIGSTOP`). I used `SIGRTMIN` because it is for application-defined purposes.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    /* Block SIGRTMIN */

    sigset_t sigmask;

    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGRTMIN);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigmask, NULL) != 0)
        exit(1);
    
    int signo;

    /* Spawn a new child */

    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1){
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (pid == 0){
        sigwait(&sigmask, &signo);  // This is to make parent start first.
        for(int i=1; i<=100; i=i+2){
            printf("I am the child: %d\n", i);

            kill(getppid(), SIGRTMIN);  // Resume parent
            sigwait(&sigmask, &signo);  // Wait for parent
        }

    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<=100; i=i+2){
            printf("I am the parent: %d\n", i);

            kill(pid, SIGRTMIN);    // Resume child
            if (i == 100)   // Parent stucks at sigwait after printing 100.
                break;
            sigwait(&sigmask, &signo);  // Wait for child
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**We blocked SIGRTMIN in the parent but how does it gets blocked in the child?**

According to [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page.

> A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's
> signal mask; the signal mask is preserved across execve(2).